# Detecting dead code in Salesforce

Tags: apex, code

In Java, there are several effective tools for detecting dead code like CodePro. I have tried but probably they won't work for Salesforce project. It is not usually an easy job to figure out the dead code in a project. How do you usually do that?

Comment: I'm working on a tool like this that I'd like to release in the next few months. As far as I'm aware, there's no such tool today, not even in paid IDEs like BrainEngine. I'd love to be wrong, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's cool, please keep me updated on this. Will that be detected during compiling or running time?

Comment: The intent is to have an org's code parsed into tokens/symbols, then attempt to remove unused tokens/symbols that aren't referenced anywhere else.

Comment: @sfdcfox Were you successful building such an unused code tool two years ago? If not maybe you want to join forces and help use port Java PMD rules to Apex as part of our #ApexMetrics open source project https://github.com/Up2Go/codeclimate-apexmetrics

Comment: IntelliJ and illuminated cloud can identify unused methods etc iirc

Comment: @sfdcfox Hey any update on the tool you were working on?

Comment: @vshake I had to shelve it for a while, but when/if I ever get the time, I still plan on doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually only do this as part of refactoring. AFAIK there are no tools like CodePro for Apex; when I find suspected dead code, it's a lot of ctrl-K file searches in Eclipse to make sure the methods aren't referred to anywhere. I don't think I've ever simply done a dead code hunt; it isn't all that problematic anyway, and so it's a pretty opportunistic process for me. Periodically I'll do a general code cleanup that involves improving test coverage and refactoring code, and as part of that usually there is some dead code deletion.

If I had to make a wishlist for developer tools / features on the platform, though, dead code detection would be near the bottom of the list. There are *so many* tools and features that the "first-class" platforms and languages have that Force.com does not.

Top of my list would probably be a real integration with a versioning system; a supported continuous integration / deployment platform; removal of all governor limits, or at least a massive consolidation of them; proper step-through debugging a la Java; a local emulation environment for fast development & test without the dreaded save-deploy-compile-run delay; folder support a la Java packages; a much more robust standard UI library; a standard exception reporting framework; debug logs that don't max out at 2MB; a heap size that is larger than the capacity of a calculator watch; a database framework that doesn't prevent me from running queries and aggregates on "large" data sets; that's just off the top of my head. Any of those above would be much more of a help to me personally than dead code detection.

TL;DR: manually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do agree with you that those stuffs are more important/helpful. But most of them are kind of impossible for 3rd party development. For example, real debugging requires a hook to salesforce runtime which is not supported at the moment. I guess dead code detection is one of the few things which is possible for third party.

Comment: Yeah true! A full Lint / CodePro suite would be awesome. Still pretty difficult to implement for a third party, though, since it would require a static analyzer for Apex (and probably VF, since that is also a code entry point).

Answer (score 2):

If you understand ANTLR 4, you can create your own linter and static analysis tool. You can create a set of methods to parse Apex in Javascript and run it in NodeJS. The definition for Java is available. You can take that definition, make it case insensitive, strings are single ticks instead of double, you have to add the logic to parse SOQL (or you can honestly write a validation to ignore it if you don't want to build the parser for it).. etc. Depending on how vast your code base is, it might be worth it to build your own if there's nothing currently on the market.

Comment: Would that strategy actually tell you if there are references across classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have test coded properly ,this will give you an indication of which code is dead .I would say not 100% but still Test code can tell you which code will never be covered and its dead .

Comment: If you are writing a unit test for each class and method, this wont help, because the dead code will still get covered by its unit tests. This will only help the lazy developers, which do write some integration tests and nothing else.

Comment: If you write test code as per your business logic and valid business scenario ,your dead code will never be covered .

Comment: You may have tests for code that is no longer used anywhere in production if you manage your tests poorly. But that's not that unlikely seeing there is little support for test management in salesforce either.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Agree with you but test classes are meant to be maintained properly .One has to be serious around test code .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava It really depends on how large your project is. For instance: we are working with several developers on the same project. Proper unit and integration tests are our life-saver when it comes down to merge, staging and release. The tradeoff is, that there will be from time to time a dead class and its unit tests, which might be forgotten to delete after refactoring. But i think that this is much better than to have a poor code coverage, because you are only testing along your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use APEX-PMD tool with eclipse.

APEX-PMD - A Static Code Analyzer for APEX: Since Apex is based on Java, most of the basic programming practices of Java apply to Apex as well. There are many code analyzers available for Java (for ex: PMD, findBugs etc) that scan the code for common programming flaws like unused variables, empty catch blocks, unnecessary object creation, and so forth.

I found a similar tool for Apex and it works very well. At least it would ease up the task of code review. Here are the steps to get this Eclipse Plugin:

1. In Eclipse, goto Help -> Install New Software.
2. Click on Add.
3. Populate Name field as: Apex PMD
4. Populate the Location field with http://codescan.villagechief.com/eclipse/
5. Hit Ok.
6. The plugin details would be fetched by eclipse.
7. Expand the tree and select Apex PMD
8. Hit Next, accept the agreement and let eclipse install the plugin.
9. Once installed, the plugin will ask to restart eclipse.
10. After eclipse has started, just right click on any of the folders that contain Apex Classes. Select ApexPMD -> Run ApexPMD
11. It would popup the "ApexPMD View" which will show you all the basic errors (check attached snapshot).
12. If the view is not visible go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> ApexPMD View

Note that not all errors would need to fixed. But at least you would know the most critical areas of the code which have to be fixed.

Comment: PMD is static code analyzer .How will it detect unused code ?